# Flag wave animation as the app background

Tags: java, android, eclipse, animation, graphics

I need to put a flag waving animation as my Android background. The only way I found is creating number of images which shows each motion in waving and calling them.

Instead, is there a better way? Some languages got basic animation options like `wave(), shake()` etc, so is there any command in android so I can animate the image, without using number of images?

Or else, is there a way I can set a Flash animation (.swf) as the background?